# Error loading notebook in subfolder, fine if I rename the folder

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a very peculiar situation where I can't access a jupyter notebook from a specific subfolder.
My directory is something like this

```
~/.../Folder/Subfolder/notebook.ipynb
```

The subfolder has been created by someone else. If I start my jupyter server in Folder and go into the subfolder and then try to open the notebook, I get an error saying "Error loading notebook. error". It doesn't say anything specific.

I can open the file if I start the server directly in the subfolder. 
I can even open the file if I start the server in Folder and rename Subfolder e.g. to Subfolder2.
However I don't really want to rename the subfolder.

What could the reason for this be? Some access right? But why would I be able to access it from the subfolder then?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually an adblocker issue due to the name of the subfolder being 'adwords' since I did an analysis on Google adwords. Interestingly the adblocker (AdBlockPlus) had no problem with 'adwords2'.

I was able to solve this problem by adding localhost to the adblocker's whitelist.

Yay!